# How to GET url from GitLab CI/CD

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a public server with notification service.

I want to trigger notification using GET url like this:

www.thisisexample.com/ci-start-ping

(when you open this link in a browser it will trigger notification)

How can I get url in GitLab CI/CD job?

Answer (score 0):

assuming your base image is Linux based, with [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html)

```
script:
  - curl https://www.thisisexample.com/ci-start-ping
```